# How do I use 'blast' in this context?

Tags: grammar

Please tell me the proper use of ***blast***  as a verb and what the difference is between

> The cylinder has blasted.

and

> The cylinder has been blasted.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between them isn't the verb *blast*. It is about then being active or passive sentences.

"The cylinder has blasted" means that 'the cylinder` blasted by itself, and no one or nothing was affected.

"The cylinder has been blasted"`means that`the cylinder` was blasted by someone or something.

Comment: Thank you for giving an answer, but please take more care with grammar, punctuation, and formatting. From the Help centre: "We don't expect every answer to be perfect, but answers with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read." (http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @RoaringFish sorry I'm not go in English. I just want to explain my idea :) And thank you for helping me edit it.